# Android custom action bar gobal

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a problem with the AppCombat.Light action bar. I want to customize my actionbar but I want to reference the layout globaly. Currently I would have to change the actionbar in each Activity like this:

```
private void setupActionBar() {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_layout);

    ImageButton tmp = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.action_bar_button);
    tmp.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico_nav);
    tmp.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

XML:

[image]

But I want to specify the layout parameters in my style sheet. Is this possible?

Currently my action bar looks like this:

[image: current action bar]
but I want an action bar which looks like this:

[image: desired action bar]

Now my question is:

Can I customize my aciton bar in a xml file? If so how can I apply it on all activities?

PS: I dont want to edit the action bar programatically!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should create an Activity class and make all of your activities inherit from it. Then you just write your code once.

Comment: Yes I already tried that but my action bar button changes its icon depending which activity is running. So I would still have to make changes in each activity. Thats because I included an imagebutton in the action_bar_layout.xml file so I could align the button on the left side of the layout. Any ideas?